# Python read text file and keep it open

Tags: python

I have a text file that I read in with Python and I then determine the line numbers of lines that contain particular keywords. For some reason, I find that I have to open the file each time I search for a different keyword. I've tried using a with statement to keep the file open, but this does not seem to work.

In the example below, I find the line number of the last line in the file as well as the first line that contains the string 'Results'

```
with open(MyFile,'r') as f:
    lastline = sum(1 for line in f)

    for num, line in enumerate(f): 
        if 'Results' in line:
            ResultLine=num   
            break
```

This successfully does the first operation (determining the last line), but not the latter. If I instead just open the file twice it works:

```
f=open(MyFile, 'r')
lastline = sum(1 for line in f)

f=open(MyFile, 'r')      
for num, line in enumerate(f): 
    if 'Results' in line:
        ResultLine=num   
        break
```

Any suggestions as to why I can't keep the file open with my with statement?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing both tasks together in a single pass over the file:

```
with open(MyFile,'r') as f:
    searching = True
    for num, line in enumerate(f): 
        if searching and 'Results' in line:
            ResultLine=num
            searching = False
    lastline = num
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work with the same file you need to rewind the file pointer. Just do `f.seek(0)` before your second enumeration

However, getting into what your code is actually doing, it can be optimized to do all in the same loop

```
with open(MyFile,'r') as f:
    lastline = 0
    ResultLine = None

    for num, line in enumerate(f): 
        if not ResultLine and 'Results' in line:
            ResultLine=num

    lastline = num # + 1 if you want a count; this is what you actually get 
                   # in your sample, the count, not the last line index
```

Comment: No need to reassign `lastline` every time through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(MyFile,'r') as f:
    lastline = sum(1 for line in f)

    ## The pointer f has reached the end of the file here
    ## Need to reset pointer back to beginning
    f.seek(0)

    for num, line in enumerate(f): 
        if 'Results' in line:
            ResultLine=num   
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

`with` creates a `contextmanager`

contextmanagers will automatically clean up after them selves when you exit their scope ... (ie close the filehandle)

**this answer only addresses why your filehandle is closed when you exit the with statement**

see http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/ for some more info about the `with` statement and contextmanagers (first link that came up on googling for "file contextmanager")

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you've effectively read the entire file once already, so when you go to `enumerate` the lines, there's nothing left to fetch.

You should read the lines all at once, and evaluate *that* instead.

```
f = open(MyFile, 'r')
lines = list(f)

# operate on lines instead of f!
# ...
```